# Как добавить alert после оформления заказа, но только в случае успешной валидации

Tags: javascript

Это разметка для окна оформления заказа. Хочу навесить alert (в будущем переделаю на адекватное модальное окно) на кнопку Оформить заказ, но только после успешного заполнения формы валидации.
`

```
<div class="basket">
        <div class="basket-container order-basket" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" data-target="second">
            <div class="basket-content order-basket-content">
                <div class="order-basket-top">
                    <h2 class="order-basket-title">Оформление заказа</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="order-basket-info">
                    <div class="order-basket-quantity order-basket-info-item">Товаров в заказе: <span></span> </div>
                    <div class="order-basket-summ order-basket-info-item">Общая сумма заказа: <span></span> </div>
                    <div class="order-basket-products order-basket-info-item">
                        <button class="order-basket-btn">Состав заказа</button>
                        <ul class="order-basket-list">
                        </ul>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form action="#" class="order-basket-form order" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                   
                    <label class="order-label">
                        <input class="input input-name order-input" type="text" data-validate-field="name" name="Имя" placeholder="Введите имя">
                    </label>
                    <label class="order-label">
                        <input class="input input-mail order-input" type="email" data-validate-field="email" name="Email" placeholder="Введите email">
                    </label>
                    <label class="order-label">
                        <input class="input input-tel order-input" type="tel" data-validate-field="tel" name="Телефон" placeholder="Введите телефон">
                    </label>
                    <button class="order-btn btn">Оформить заказ</button>
                </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`А это скрипт на самоочищение корзины:`

```
const clearCart = () => {
  productArray = [];
  price = 0;

  cartProductsList.querySelector('.simplebar-content').innerHTML = '';
  
  printQuantity();
  printFullPrice();

  updateStorage();
}
```

`
В этом месте человек заполнил форму валидации, заказ ушел на почту, корзина очистилась от товара.
Из-за неопытности - мозгов не хватает сделать это самостоятельно.

Попробовал навесить событие на clearCart, но сделал это криво - не получилось.

Comment: Как же вы можете на функцию навесить событие (`Попробовал навесить событие на clearCart`)? И вы так и не показали паттерн валидации...

Comment: Блин, прошу прощения за беспокойство, что-то я с недосыпа ну уж очень сильно затупил. Можно просто вставить Alert в этот скрипт: const clearCart = () => {
  productArray = []
  price = 0;
  cartProductsList.querySelector('.simplebar-content').innerHTML = '';  
  printQuantity();
  printFullPrice();
  updateStorage();
}  В общем я не заметил очевидного решения. А по поводу "навесить событие" - это я в терминологии ошибся.